# Weighted normals more than 100

Tags: normals

[image]

[image]

Can I use more that 100 on Weighted Normals modifier or is there any other way to achieve Left Cube effect?
Thx

Comment: The answer is no, you can't add values > 100 on the weighted normal modifier. Maybe if you can add a little bit more info about your end goal we can help you achieve it in another way ?

Comment: I would like a quick and easy way to invert the smooth shading so that surfaces look even sharper than flat like on the example above